# Question from logical reasoning

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This is a question from syllogism(reasoning). It reads thus:
Statements: $1$. All $A$ are $B$

$2$. All $B$ are $C$.

Conclusion:  Some $C$ may or may not be $A$.
I am confused about the validity of this conclusion.  The definite conclusion that one can draw from these statements is: Some $C$ are $A$. And there is the possibility that some $C$ are not $A$. Does that mean that the given conclusion is true ? Please suggest.

Comment: See [Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Barbara_(AAA-1)): from "All A are B" and "All B are C" it follows that "All A are C".

Comment: "Some C are A".  Wrong.  A (for example) could be the empty set.

Comment: Thus, from "All A are C", we have that "Some C are A". This does not imply that "All C are A". Thus, it may happen that "Some C are not A".

Comment: Such difficulties are eliminated with a system of natural deduction with its predicates and quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't say that all C are defintely A. What you can say is that all A are defintely C.

Consider:

All tigers are mammals

All mammals are animals

What follows? All tigers are animals, yes.  All animals are tigers? No.  But of course, if I have animal, it may or may not be a tiger.